# Recursive functions for sorting

Tags: python, recursion, sorting, python-3.x

I made a few recursive functions for learning purposes which do a variety of tasks. Here is my current and functioning code:

```
def separate(p,l):
    ''' recursive function when is passed a predicate and a list returns a 2-tuple
    whose 0 index is a list of all the values in the argument list for which the     
    predicate returns True,and whose 1 index is a list of all the values in the  
    argument list for which the predicate returns False.'''
    if len(l) == 0:
        return ([],[])
    else:
        (true_list, false_list) = separate(p,l[1:])
        if p(l[0]):
            return ([l[0]] + true_list, false_list)
        else:
            return (true_list, [l[0]] + false_list)


def is_sorted(s):
    ''' recursive function when passed a list returns a bool telling whether or not 
    the values in the list are in non-descending order: lowest to highest allowing 
    repetitions. '''
    if len(s) <= 1:
        return True
    elif s[0] < s[1]:
        return is_sorted(s[1:])
    else:
        return False


def sort(l):
    ''' recursive function when passed a list; it returns a new list (not mutating 
    the passed one) with every value in the original list, but ordered in non-
    descending order. '''
    if len(l) == 0:
        return []
    else:
        (before, after) = separate(lambda i: i < l[0], l[1:])
        return sort(before) + [l[0]] + sort(after)


def compare(a,b):
    ''' a recursive function when is passed two str arguments; it returns one of 
    three str values: '<’, '=’, or '>’ which indicates the relationship between the 
    first and second parameter.'''
    if a == '' and b == '':
        return '='
    if a == '' and b != '':
        return '<'
    if a != '' and b == '':
        return '>'
    if a[0] > b[0]:
        return '>'
    if a[0] < b[0]:
        return '<'
    else:
        return compare(a[1:],b[1:])
```

Is there a way to write these recursive functions in a cleaner/concise way? Any help would be great.

Comment: Please ask a separate question for `code_metric()`. It is neither recursive, nor does it reuse your other functions. (I believe you have missed the point of the exercise as well.)

Comment: @200_success- WIll do. I know I missed the point of the exercise, but that's what I needed help with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`is_sorted()` does not behave as described or as expected. It requires elements to be strictly increasing rather than non-descending.

The implementation and docstring could be shorter as well.

```
def is_sorted(list):
    """Recursively checks if the elements in the list are in non-descending order."""
    return len(list) <= 1 or (list[0] <= list[1] and is_sorted(list[1:]))
```

I'd expect that trimming lists at the end would be more efficient (though the code definitely looks weirder):

```
def is_sorted(list):
    """Recursively checks if the elements in the list are in non-descending order."""
    return len(list) <= 1 or (list[-2] <= list[-1] and is_sorted(list[:-1]))
```

---

`compare()` has some redundant checks.

Here, I feel that the `else` is incongruous. Either rely on the early `return`s, or use `else` in conjunction with `elif` everywhere.

```
def compare(a,b):
    """Lexicographically compares strings a and b, returning '<', '=', or '>'."""
    if a == '' and b == '':
        return '='
    if a == '':
        return '<'
    if b == '':
        return '>'
    if a[0] > b[0]:
        return '>'
    if a[0] < b[0]:
        return '<'
    return compare(a[1:], b[1:])
```

Instead of checking for `== ''`, consider checking the length, so that the function can operate on lists as well.

Comment: @200_success- using the is_sorted function when I try to do `is_sorted([])` it should return True but it gives me error stating `return len(list) <= 1 or (list[0] <= list[1] and is_sorted(list[1:]))
TypeError: object of type 'type' has no len()`

Comment: @200_success- compare has the same issue. when I do `compare('','')` it returns < when it should be =.  `compare('','abc')` return > when it should be <. Similarly, the problem persists if any of the strings compared is empty. Works perfectly fine when comparing with non-empty string args.

Comment: @LucyBen If you're getting `TypeError: object of type 'type' has no len()`, then you probably missed the detail that I renamed the parameter from `s` to `list`.

Comment: How is it possible that `compare('', '')` returns `'<'`?  That's handled by the first conditional, which I didn't change at all.

Comment: @200_success- nm..I made some minor errors in transcribing the code. It works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you be more consistent in not combining `if` followed by a statement sequence ending in `return` with an `else` (I left out the comments):

```
def separate(p,l):
    if len(l) == 0:
        return ([],[])
    (true_list, false_list) = separate(p,l[1:])
    if p(l[0]):
        return ([l[0]] + true_list, false_list)
    return (true_list, [l[0]] + false_list)
```

as you do e.g. in `compare()`.

In `compare()` I would nest the conditions (arbitrarily based on `a`):

```
def compare(a,b):
    if a == '':
        if b == '':
            return '='
        return '<'
    if a != '':
        if b == '':
            return '>'
    if a[0] > b[0]:
        return '>'
    if a[0] < b[0]:
        return '<'
    return compare(a[1:],b[1:])
```

That way it is more clear to me that `compare()` never ends without a return value.

Your comments should at least use triple **double quotes** ([PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#string-quotes)) and you should try to conform to [PEP 257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257) (docstring conventions).

Comment: @Alice- when I do `compare('','')` it returns < when it should be =.  `compare('','abc')` return > when it should be <. Similarly, the problem persists if any of the strings compared is empty. Works perfectly fine when comparing with non-empty string args.

Comment: @LucyBen it doesn't in my test program. Are you sure you are running the right tests? And the same ones that give the correct results on your own code?

Comment: @Alice- I made some minor errors in transcribing the code. It works perfectly. Thank you. any suggestions for sort function??